# Matching inputted phone number vs a document from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've setup an app where users login through the phone number auth on Firebase and I'm trying to setup logic so a user can re-login via their phone number if they already setup an account.  I'm struggling to match the inputted phone number vs a document from Firestore (I have a folder titled phoneNumbers where I capture phone setup specifically for this purpose).

FYI - the phone auth logic has been working, just need help on matching a phone number inputted to a phone number already in my database.  thanks!

```
          {
            
            print ("there is a number")
            
            let countryCodeText: String = "+1-"
            
            let phoneNumSetup = phonenumberTextField.text ?? ""
            
            let phoneNumber = countryCodeText + phoneNumSetup
            
            print("phone number given = \(phoneNumber)")
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneNumber, forKey: "phoneNumber")
            
            let db = Firestore.firestore()
            
            db.collection(Constants.ProfileData.phoneNumbers).whereField(Constants.ProfileData.phone, isEqualTo: phoneNumber).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
                guard error == nil, !(snapshot?.isEmpty ?? false) else { return }
                let document = snapshot?.documents.first
                if let userData = document?.data() {
                    let pN = userData[Constants.ProfileData.phone] as? String
                    let pNcount = pN?.count
                    
                    if pNcount! > 0 {
                        
                        print("phone number existed before")
                        
                        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
                              if let error = error {
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { _ in
                                    alert.dismiss(animated: false)
                                                    }))
                                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                                return
                              }
                            
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "verificationSegue", sender: nil)
                            
                            self.currentVerificationId = verificationID!
                        
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
                        
                            }
                        
                    }
                    else {
                        
                        print("phone number is new")
                        
                        print ("not in firebase, they need to signup!")
                        
                        self.displayAlertToWelcome2()
                        
    
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: Firestore Setup]

[image: phone input view]

Comment: The easiest way to add phone number sign-in to your app is to use [FirebaseUI](https://opensource.google.com/projects/firebaseui), which includes a drop-in, sign-in widget that implements sign-in flows for phone number sign-in, as well as password-based and federated sign-in. [This document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) describes how to implement a phone number sign-in flow using the Firebase SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out, I'm trying to query the Firestore database without being logged in!  My database is setup to only allow queries if an authorized user.  I'll have to re-think my setup on this, won't be smart to allow un-auth pings to the database.

Answer (score 0):

```
func yourFunc() {
    guard let phoneNumberInput = phonenumberTextField.text else {
        return
    }
    let phoneNumber = "+1-" + phoneNumberInput
    UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneNumber, forKey: "myApp.phoneNumber") // good practice to prefix user defaults
    
    Firestore.firestore().collection(Constants.ProfileData.phoneNumbers)
        .whereField(Constants.ProfileData.phone, isEqualTo: phoneNumber)
        .getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let doc = snapshot?.documents.first else {
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                return
            }
            if let pN = doc.get(Constants.ProfileData.phone) as? String,
               pN.count > 0 {
                print("phone number existed before")
            } else {
                print("phone number is new")
                print ("not in firebase, they need to signup!")
                self.displayAlertToWelcome2()
            }
        }
}
```